# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error happening when trying to run tests with Cucumber 7 and JUnit 5

Tags: junit, cucumber, junit5, serenity

I have a POC for running API tests using Cucumber 7, JUnit 5 and Serenity 4.
There is just one short test and a verification of the status code of a GET request. The test works fine if I try to assert the correct status code. But when I try to assert a different status code in order to make the test fail, an error related to `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` occours.
I have looked possible solutions and I think this probably has to do with incompatibilities between the JUnit dependecies in my POM file.
Yes, my POM file is still big, I intend to exclude a lot of things that are not being used, but first I need to solve this issue.
My project is on github and can be dowloaded and run locally. Link: https://github.com/renantgarcia/test-automation-example-junit5.git

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.renan</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-automation-example-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Test Automation Example with JUnit 5</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <bouncycastle.version>1.76</bouncycastle.version>
        <log4j.version>2.20.0</log4j.version>
        <json.version>20231013</json.version>
        <rest-assured.version>5.3.2</rest-assured.version>
        <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>
        <junit-vintage.version>5.10.0</junit-vintage.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.10.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.10.0</junit-platform.version>
        <maven-surefire-junit.version>3.2.5</maven-surefire-junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>7.14.0</cucumber.version>
        <serenity.version>4.0.43</serenity.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.2.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <failsafe-plugin.version>3.1.2</failsafe-plugin.version>
        <serenity-plugin.version>3.9.7</serenity-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
            <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-reports</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <filters>
            <filter>src/test/resources/resources_filtered/env_${env}.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/CucumberRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-surefire-junit.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>LOCAL</id>
            <properties>
                <env>LOCAL</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>DEV</id>
            <properties>
                <env>DEV</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>QA</id>
            <properties>
                <env>QA</env>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

The error I get when I use `mvn clean verify` to run the tests:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/AssumptionViolatedException
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporter.isAssumptionFailure(SerenityReporter.java:948)
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporter.failed(SerenityReporter.java:890)
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporter.recordStepResult(SerenityReporter.java:843)
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporter.handleResult(SerenityReporter.java:824)
        at io.cucumber.core.plugin.SerenityReporter.handleTestStepFinished(SerenityReporter.java:372)
        at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:51)
        at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:12)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.SynchronizedEventBus.send(SynchronizedEventBus.java:47)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.emitTestStepFinished(TestStep.java:116)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:67)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
        at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$4(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:112)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
        at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.CucumberEngineExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberEngineExecutionContext.java:109)
        at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.NodeDescriptor$PickleDescriptor.execute(NodeDescriptor.java:168)
        at io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.NodeDescriptor$PickleDescriptor.execute(NodeDescriptor.java:90)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 22 more
```

I am expecting no errors when I try to force the test to fail (using a random status code in the assertion).
I haven't found any good solutions on the internet yet, so I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: You‘re mixing incompatible versions of some tools. Please show the test code that fails, so that the culprit can be identified

Comment: You should report this as a bug to the Serenity project. The `SerenityReporter` depends on JUnit 4 but doesn't seem to have declared it as a transitive dependency.

Comment: Lol... JUnit 4 is explicitly made an optional dependency but the code has a hard dependency. https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/blob/52529160121c8f0c8e220f1778b492db93d8e5cb/serenity-cucumber/pom.xml#L117

Comment: The code that fails is inside the function with the @Then Cucumber annotation in SomeClass.java. It breaks at line 44, where an assertion function is called (assertEquals) from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions`